# xsd rules with elements with same name but not same attributes

Tags: xsd, xls

i have a xml file something like that

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<list>
   <some_element code="AA">some text</some_element>
   <same_name_tag style="header1">some text</same_name_tag>
   <same_name_tag style="header2">some text</same_name_tag>
   <same_name_tag style="header3">some text</same_name_tag>

 <sometimes_here_can_be_tag/>
 <same_name_tag style="body1">
     <new number="1"/> 
     <new number="2"/>
  </same_name_tag>

  <same_name_tag style="body2">
     <new number="1"/> 
     <new number="2"/>
  </same_name_tag>
</list>
```

xsd i need something like that (it is wrong)

```
 <xs:element name="list">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="some_element" type="element" />
       <xs:element name="some_name_tag" type="header" />
          <xs:choice   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="sometimes_here_can_be_tag" type="sometimes"/>
            <xs:element name ="some_name_tag"  type="body"/>
          </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

so i have 2 problems

1. i need set a header 1,2,3 as uniq that can not contains `<new numbers/>` and they must be before  `<same_name_tag style="bodytags">`
2. if `<xs:attribute code ="AA">`of some_element, attribute number must be 100 max, if BB than 50 max

Thank you

Comment: Please describe your problem in a more understandable matter.

Comment: I think the OP has described the problem well.